# Can I copy Visual Studio to a client's machine to debug issues?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

My client's machine is located in a local domain so I cannot remote debug. Can I copy my Visual Studio folder to their machine and debug on site?

Comment: Nope, this is not doable. If you want VS on their PC, then try installing Visual Studio Express edition and see if that helps you debug the issue. If you want a Visual Studio edition greater then Express (e.g. Professional, Premium, Ultimate) to be installed, then you will have to make sure you have a licence for it.

Answer (score 0):

The best question is to ask yourself how do I improve logging and tracing mechanism to debug any issues.